# Using pandas to display xlsx file content

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot and i am attempting to display the data from a specified sheet of a xlsx file

this is the section of code

```
def showme(bot,update):
    team = pd.ExcelFile(r"sheetname.xlsx")
    ytd = pd.read_excel(r"sheetname.xlsx", sheet_name=5)
    q3 = pd.read_excel(r"sheetname.xlsx", sheet_name=3)
    update.message.reply_text(ytd)
```

But when i Call on the showme nothing happens.

I have the imports correct, and in the build `print(ytd)` displayed the information i wanted.

Any ideas where i may have gone wrong ? I do suspect it is to do with `update.message.reply_text(ytd)` part

Comment: Then can you show us the `update.message.reply_text()` function?

Comment: @YilunZhang i'm sorry, i dont know what you mean ? The error im getting in my log file is `TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: We can only help if you show us this function: `update.message.reply_text()`, otherwise we don't know where the problem is. From the error message, it seems like in that function, a method is expecting a json serializable object rather than a pandas dataframe, you can try to convert your `ytd` to a json object using `ytd.to_json()`.

Comment: adding `.to_json()` did give me an output, thank you for that. I will go away now and try to make its look nicer. Thank you